# Problems reading local text file with [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile...] with Objective-c returns null

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This does not seem so complex. I just want to create a string object with the contents of a local text file called "test.txt" which I have placed in the root of my project.

I am trying to load it w/ the following code.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];    
NSString *textData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


//The below works, but not my above... not sure why.
//textData = @"TEST TEST";


NSLog(@"Some text from a file of %@", textData);
NSLog(@"The length of the string is %lu", [textData length]);
```

The output from this code is 
"Some text from a file of (null)"
"The length of the string is 0"

I am not sure why this is returning null instead of the contents of my text file. The encoding for the file seems appropriate. Also, the file exists. Am I dragging the file to the wrong location? Do I have to add it to my NSBundle mainBundle in some way?

Thanks!

Comment: For sure it is test.txt and I dragged it into right into the project and made sure "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)"

Comment: Here is a picture of where I dragged my test.txt file in and copied it. http://imgur.com/VhBDF Thank you everyone for the help so far. I really appreciate it.

Comment: A quick and simple thing to test is that the file in question is actually included in the build product. Go to the .app in Finder, right click to get the context menu, then click Show Package Contents. Your file should be in Contents/Resources, and maybe in en.lproj, depending on whether you localized it in Xcode.

Comment: Monolo, thanks for the advice. What I saw is that I can not open the .app in finder, maybe because it is a console application? But I did find that if I copied my test.txt file manually in the terminal to the location in which the binary was compiled it will then read the file :) Now to just figure out how to get it working automatically. I'm going to consider this question solved at this point. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

If you actually fill in the `error` parameter in `+stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` then it would *tell you* why it's returning `nil`. You really ought to do that. The likely reason is there is no file at that path (or you don't have permissions to read it).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am quite new at this. Thankfully I found that there is an NSError object. So I created one and then set error: to this object. Did an NSLog of it and it came back stating "The file name is invalid." So I def have a problem w/ the actual file name/location. I will have to investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog the filePath and see if it's nil. If the filePath is nil, I think you didn't put the file in right place. You should drag the file into the project navigator of your project in Xcode.
Also, double check the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Log your filePath to see if it can actually find the file, if not, you probably add your test.txt in a wrong way. To add to main bundle, drag your test.txt into your xcode project, when prompted, just tick Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed) and select Create groups for any added folders.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers here helped a little bit. In particular the suggestion to fill in the error: in a way that does not return nil.

Eventually I found that I had to manually copy the .txt file I was trying to open to the same directory as the binary that was compiled. Just copying it into the xcode project did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem as you, Vincent. My understanding is that because I am making an console-based application, it doesn't compile and include files within a bundle in the same way that an iOS app would. Therefore, it's not including the file as expected. I was able to get it to work by typing out the full directory location of the file on my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop your test.txt file to Build Phases->copy bundle resources